# Is it possible to display a view in front of the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have two fragments. One displays my general content (fragment A). The other, fragment B, is displayed over the top of fragment A. I would like for my action bar to have a z-order in the middle of these two layouts. That is, the fragment B would be displayed in front of the action bar.

My question is, is it possible to display a view in front of the action bar?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

After all, applications can already display in full screen and not in full screen with the action bar whenever they like. You can set that programmatically yourself in Java.

```
import android.app.ActionBar;

...
// Show action bar
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.show();

...
// Hide action bar
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Just make sure there is a good reason to alternate this common UI convention on Android.

Comment: That hides the ActionBar; however, I am wanting to overlap the bar (partially, or completely).

Comment: Yes, if you want to partially overlap it, you'll probably want to make a transparent Activity that you place on top of it.

Comment: It is not possible to display an activity over another. Rather, I can layer a fragment on top of my main fragment. The question is, how do I ensure that the top level fragment is indeed at a higher z order than the action bar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android/2700683#2700683

Comment: Actually, a z-order thing might be possible as well with the animation framework, I remember seeing a presentation by Chet Haase. I'm just a bit fuzzy on the details. I'll have to look it up.

Comment: Here is one way to do what you want from Chet Haas. Chet works at Google and wrote the android animation framework. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ho8vk61lVIU Chet also has other easier ways you can do the same thing at higher api levels. It's just that I don't have the time to look through all of his presentations/youtube videos.

Comment: @MM. Did you ever find a way to do this?